# EdiFact, mapping Copaym - Coplat messages

Tags: mapping, standards, edifact

I have a Coplat message in the following format

```
DEB1234567890    5   CODE1     5   2007020610471COPLAT0
(... other data here ....)

DEB1234567890    5   CODE2     5   2007020610471COPLAT0
(... other data here ....)

FIN00000245
```

the above message has two DEB sections as you can notice.

I want to create a Copaym message that can be mapped to that Coplat message, this is an example of a Copaym message with one BGM segment.

```
UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE1'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'
```

I want to create two messages like this one to be translated to the above Coplat message, means when translated, I must get 2 DEB sections with CODE1 and CODE2 respectivily, I tried this :

```
UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE1'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'

UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE2'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'
```

but I got syntax error, so I makes all the data inside one UNB segment which works, but the generated Coplat has just one DEB with CODE1, this is the message :

```
UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE1'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'

UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'
```

One UNB and 2 UNH segments inside.
Can anyone help how to make a Copaym message so I get 2 DEB segments with CODE1 and CODE2?

Answer (score 0):

that's the correct format, you have just to specify different Interchange identifires for the two messages

```
UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE1'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'

UNB+UNOC:2+1234567890:5+CODE2'
UNH+1000000+COPAYM:0:4.2:RT'
BGM+903:ZZZ+1000000'
    (... other data here ....)
UNT+62:1000000'
UNZ+2+091000000'
```